# Steps for solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2=\frac{a}{x}+b$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha

According to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+dy%2Fdx-y%5E2+%3D+a+%2B+b%2Fx),

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2=\frac{b}{x}+a$$

The equation above has the solution;

[image]

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants. $_1F_1(a;b;x)$ and $U(a,b,x)$ are the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function and confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind, respectively.

I don't know how Wolfram got this solution, can anyone here help me please?

Thank you guys

Comment: @Elsayed: The stated problem and link do not match. Which is correct?

Comment: I'm so sorry, i forgot to square the $y$ in the equation i stated @Moo, I corrected it now, thank you for mentioning.

Comment: This is *almost* a Bernoulli ODE. However. The presence of the non-homogeneous term $\frac{b}{x}+a$ makes it troublesome. The "closed form" solution is not of much use to be honest. I think straightforward numerical methods are best here.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know ? All the details leading to these particular coefficients and parameters, or the general method that was used ?

Comment: I want know how Walfram got to this solution @YvesDaoust

Comment: I believe you should ask WA developers...

Comment: As shown in the answers, it is likely that this is solved as a Riccati equation, leading to a linear second order ODE. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2+\frac{b}{x}+a$$
This is a Riccati ODE. The usual change of function is :
$$y(x)=-\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}\quad;\quad y'=-\frac{u''}{u}+\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}$$
$$y'=\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2+\frac{b}{x}+a=-\frac{u''}{u}+\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}$$
$$\frac{b}{x}+a=-\frac{u''}{u}$$
$$u''-\left(\frac{b}{x}+a\right)u=0$$
This is the general confluent hypergeometric differential equation :

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html

From Eq.$(1)$ in this page determine $A$, $f(x)$ and $h(x)$. This leads to :

[image]

Then computing $y(x)=-\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$ will lead to the solution.

Comment: Hi Jean ! Nice way (as usual). Cheers :-)

Comment: What was your $A$, $f(x)$ and $h(x)$? Its hard for me to analyze the general equation!

Comment: $A$ , $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ are the notations used Eq.$(1)$ in the page referenced : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html Compare  with $u''-\left(\frac{b}{x}+a\right)u=0$ in order to find  $A$ , $f(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

What is making problem for $$\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2=\frac{b}{x}+a$$ is $a$. For $a=0$, you would get the "simple"
$$y=\frac{c_1 J_1\left(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{x}\right)+\sqrt{b} \sqrt{x} \left(\left(c_1-2\right)
   J_0\left(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{x}\right)-c_1 J_2\left(2 \sqrt{b}
   \sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{2 \left(1-c_1\right) x J_1\left(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{x}\right) }$$ which can also write
$$y=-\frac 1x\frac{\, _0\tilde{F}_1(;1;-b x)}{ \, _0\tilde{F}_1(;2;-b x)}$$ where appears the regularized confluent hypergeometric function.

Now, for $a \neq 0$, the "monster"
$$\frac{\sqrt{-a} \left(-c_1 (U(k,0,2 t)-2 U(k,1,2 t))-2 (t+1) \,
   _1F_1(k+1;2;2 t)-2 (k-1) t \, _1F_1(k+1;3;2 t)\right)}{c_1 U(k,0,2
   t)+2 t \, _1F_1(k+1;2;2 t)} $$ where $t=x\sqrt{-a}$ and $k=-\frac b{2\sqrt{-a}}$.